# Import files from a directory choose via Manipulate

Tags: manipulate, gui-construction, files-and-directories, scheduling

I thought I write a super-simple program to import all (Excel)files from a directory a user can choose>

```
Manipulate[
 dirName = SetDirectory[DirectoryName[importOneFileName]];
 dataFiles = FileNames["*.xls*", dirName]

 , {{importOneFileName, "", "Load Files"}, FileNameSetter[#] &}
 ]
```

This is actually working. However, I always get an error messages regarding the `SetDirectory[]`. I can, of course, write

```
Quiet@SetDirectory[DirectoryName[importOneFileName]]
```

which works. But having an error message always seems odd.
I found that others have similar problems with `FileNameSetter[]`. Maybe `Quiet` is the best that can be done here.

Comment: Why not just do this? Doesn't it accomplish the same thing, in much less code? `DynamicModule[{selectedDir}, Column[{FileNameSetter[Dynamic[selectedDir], "Directory"], Dynamic[FileNames["*.xlsx", selectedDir]]}]]`

Comment: Most likely ... I know how to use Manipulate, but haven't had time to properly dive into Dynamics, although it seems much more flexible. But thanks so far!

Comment: I believe it is a more straightforward way to achieve what you're after.

Comment: just change `FileNameSetter[#] &` to `FileNameSetter[#, "Directory"] &`?

Comment: @kglr Simplifies the code, which is nice, but the error message is still there.

Comment: @user6014 I agree, but I have some more code in the Manipulate, which I need to deal with.

Comment: These errors usually occur due to the absence of the initial argument for `SetDirectory`. Just define the default value `importOneFileName` outside the `Manipulate` and it will get out the errors.

Answer (score 1):

Just don't run the code if the file name is not set:

```
Manipulate[
  If[
    FileExistsQ @ importOneFileName,

    dirName = SetDirectory[DirectoryName[importOneFileName]];
    dataFiles = FileNames["*.xls*", dirName],

    ""
  ], 
  {{importOneFileName, " ", "Load Files"}, FileNameSetter[#] &  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use `SystemDialogInput` with the `"Directory"` input type to have the user select a directory directly. Check a directory has been chosen by comparing the result to `$Canceled`.

```
dir = SystemDialogInput["Directory"];
If[dir =!= $Canceled,
 "Process directory",
 "No directory to process"
 ]
```

Hope this helps.